# Dropdown with Checkbox in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS which is generated for around 50-60 items.

Say, the report shows Country name on one scale and their population on another.
When the graph is generated, it shows around 100 countries.
If I want to see population of only UK, US, India and China. Then I Should have an option to select the countries of my choice.

Having one dropdown and allowing them to select only one country at a time is simple.

I have no idea on how I can have a checkbox in dropdown to allow multiple selections.

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to search for [Multi-valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). If you open the properties of the parameter there will be an option something like "Allow multiple values". Reporting services will handle the UI with checkboxes.

One important thing to know about multi-valued parameters is how to use them in your query. Suppose your parameter `@CountryId` is being filled with this query:

```sql
SELECT CountryId, -- This will be the value for the parameter
       CountryName, -- The label for the parameter
FROM   Country
```

If you set this parameter to allow multiple-values, reporting services will generate the multi-select UI for you. When executing any subsequent query that uses the parameter, before sending the query to your SQL server it will replace the parameter with a comma-seperated list of `CountryId` values. So this query:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    MyDataTable
WHERE   MyDataTable.CountryId IN (@CountryID)
```

Will be sent to SQL server as something like this, supposing there are 3 countries selected:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    MyDataTable
WHERE   MyDataTable.CountryId IN (1001,1002,1003)
```

Comment: That helps in query part, but how do I take care of UI ?

Comment: As I mention in my answer, reporting services will do that for you. If there are multiple available values for your parameter then SSRS will put a checkbox in front of each one in the dropdown, and add an option "Select all".

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I have modified my report as suggested and it works, but the query doesnot not work for multiple items. It works well when only single item has been checked. I think I might have to do something with comma seperation code. Do you have any idea of the same ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact problem is, but I've included a short example on how to use a MV-parameter in a query. For more info I suggest checking the MSDN, there's bound to be a few tutorials around.

Comment: Nopes, It doesnot split by itself. But I used a Comma split function in my procedure to fix that issue. Thanks for all you help.